# Using Expl3 token-list variables where token lists are called for

Tags: expl3, token-lists

The code below illustrates the trouble I’m having. It seems I cannot directly use a token-list variable where a token list is called for, but why, and how can I get the result I want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\bool_new:N \found_bool

\cs_new_protected:Npn \find_token_in_tl:Nn #1#2
  {
    \bool_set_false:N \found_bool
    \tl_map_inline:nn { #2 }
      {
        \token_if_eq_charcode:NNT ##1 #1
          {
            \bool_set_true:N \found_bool
            \tl_map_break:
          }
      }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand { \FindTokInList } { m m }
  {
    \find_token_in_tl:Nn #1 {#2}
    \bool_if:NTF \found_bool { ! } { ? }
  }

\tl_const:Nn \punct_tl {,.;:}

\NewDocumentCommand { \FindTokInPunctList } { m }
  {
    \find_token_in_tl:Nn #1 \punct_tl
    \bool_if:NTF \found_bool { ! } { ? }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
dot: \FindTokInList{.}{,.;:} % finds token & prints “!”

x: \FindTokInList{x}{,.;:} % doesn’t find token & prints “?”

dot: \FindTokInPunctList{.} % doesn’t find token & prints “?”, but why?

x: \FindTokInPunctList{x} % doesn’t find token & prints “?”
\end{document}
```

Comment: Generating a variant `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \find_token_in_tl:Nn {NV}` and using that in `\FindTokInPunctList` fixes the problem but I'm not completely sure why.

Comment: Why not using `\tl_if_in:NnTF` to begin with?

Comment: @egreg One reason could be because the charcode test is looser than `\tl_if_in:NnTF`.  For instance, one wants to put a given space both before an active `:` or an other `:`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch, that’s something I hadn’t even considered, though it does explain the other results I mentioned in comments below. I may be out of my depth here… ☺

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are token lists and token list variables, which are `n` and `N` type, respectively. The LaTeX3 programming layer is careful not to expand anything it should not, so when you do

```
\tl_map_inline:nn {#2} { <code> }
```

with `#2` = `\l_JS_punct_tl` you passing the single token `\l_JS_punct_tl` to the `<code>`, *not* the content of the variable. For that, you want

```
\tl_map_inline:Nn #2 { <code> }
```

You could also pass the value using

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_map_inline:nn { V }
\tl_map_inline:Vn #2 { <code> }
```

but it's not necessary.

---

As an aside, LaTeX3 code variables should always be named

```
\<scope>_<module>_<description>_<type>
```

so I've used `\l_JS_punct_tl` in place of `\punct_tl` in the question.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\c_JS_punct_tl`? Also `\found_bool` should be `\l_JS_found_bool`

Comment: @egreg I'd not spotted that it's a constant, but this seems wrong to me anyway as I'd expect a real case to make this user-definable. I'd noticed the bool, but made my comment general to cover this case too.

Answer (score 6):

There are already `\tl_if_in:nnTF` and `\tl_if_in:NnTF`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand { \FindTokInList } { m m }
 {
  \tl_if_in:nnTF {#2} {#1} { ! } { ? }
 }

\tl_const:Nn \c_JS_punct_tl {,.;:}

\NewDocumentCommand { \FindTokInPunctList } { m }
 {
  \tl_if_in:NnTF \c_JS_punct_tl { #1 } { ! } { ? }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
dot: \FindTokInList{.}{,.;:} % finds token & prints !

x: \FindTokInList{x}{,.;:} % doesn't find token & prints ?

dot: \FindTokInPunctList{.} % finds token & prints !

x: \FindTokInPunctList{x} % doesn't find token & prints ?
\end{document}
```

Comment: That was helpful! It’s too easy for an `expl3` newbie to miss things like that, and I’m glad of the help.

Comment: @J.C.Salomon It's difficult to remember all the functions; but a couple of guidelines are: basic tasks are covered and the naming conventions are good. So looking for `tl_if_in` conduced to the right functions.

Comment: My actual use-case looks more like `\token_new:Nn\period{.} \tl_if_in:nnTF{,.;}{\period}{!}{?}`, using a token variable (actually `\l_peek_token`).

Comment: @J.C.Salomon The use case you describe in that last comment is not covered by `\tl_if_in` since that `\period` token is an implicit token, which does not "look" like a period character (but has the same meaning, which means that it behaves the same when typeset).