# List Version of \str_if_eq

Tags: macros, expansion, expl3, comma-separated-list

I am using `\str_if_eq:xxTF{\A}{\Target}{<true>}{<false}` to execute the `<true>` or `<false>` code if `\A`=`\Target`.

What is the list version equivalent of this?

So I am looking for something such as

```
\str_if_in_list:xxTF{\A}{\TargetList}{<true>}{<false}
```

which executes the appropriate `<true>`/`<false>` if `A` is in the *list* (CSV) `\TargetList`?

I have to admit I have not tried for too long on this as I really can't read `expl3` syntax yet, but a few of the macros presented at [Using Expl3 token-list variables where token lists are called for](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64110/using-expl3-token-list-variables-where-token-lists-are-called-for) looked interesting, but I was not able to get them to work.

So, in the MWE below, by changing `\GetTexFilePath` and `\GetTexFilePathExpandable` the last three lines should *not* have an `xxx` in the directory path.
The current output is:

[image]

### Notes:

- The `\TargetList` is always a macro that contains the list.
- The source of the comparison is *usually* a value declared with `\newtoks` as per the MWE below (not sure if that matters).

---

### References:

Before people get the wrong idea and think that I actually understand some `expl3` syntax, here is where that code originated from:

- [Text being output when none should be](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42742/text-being-output-when-none-should-be)
- [How to expand values stored in a token defined by newtoks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46323/how-to-expand-values-stored-in-a-token-defined-by-newtoks)

Possible clue to solution:

- [Using Expl3 token-list variables where token lists are called for](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64110/using-expl3-token-list-variables-where-token-lists-are-called-for)

---

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\NotSpecialDirectory}{foo}

%% These directories should never have an "xxx" in the path.
%% The values here do NOT change at run time.
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46323/how-to-expand-values-stored-in-a-token-defined-by-newtoks
\protected\def\SpecialDirectory{AAA}
\protected\def\SpecialDirectoryB{BBB}
\protected\def\SpecialDirectoryC{CCC}


%% The list of members here do NOT change at run time.
\newcommand{\ListOfSpecialDirectories}{%
    \SpecialDirectory,%
    \SpecialDirectoryB,% 
    \SpecialDirectoryC,% <-- would prefer to be allowed extra comma here, but
                       %     can do without that if it adds too much complexity
}

\newtoks{\CurrentDirectory}


\ExplSyntaxOn%%% These work fine...
% Determine path: Always #1/xxx#2/#3 unless #1=\SpecialDirectory
\NewDocumentCommand{\GetTexFilePathOld}{m m m}{%
    \str_if_eq:xxTF{#1}{\SpecialDirectory}{#1/#2/#3}{#1/xxx#2/#3}%
}%


\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\GetTexFilePathExpandableOld}{m m m}{%
    \str_if_eq:xxTF{#1}{\SpecialDirectory}{#1/#2/#3}{#1/xxx#2/#3}%
}%


%%% how do I define these ...
% Determine path: Always #1/xxx#2/#3 unless #1 is in \ListOfSpecialDirectories

% Don't work: % \tl_if_in:nnTF  \str_if_in:nnTF,  \str_if_in:xxTF
\NewDocumentCommand{\GetTexFilePath}{m m m}{%
    \str_if_eq:xxTF{#1}{\ListOfSpecialDirectories}{#1/#2/#3}{#1/xxx#2/#3}%
}%


\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\GetTexFilePathExpandable}{m m m}{%
    \str_if_eq:xxTF{#1}{\ListOfSpecialDirectories}{#1/#2/#3}{#1/xxx#2/#3}%
}%
\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}
\noindent\textbf{These work fine:}

\CurrentDirectory={\NotSpecialDirectory}
Should have xxx in path: 
    \GetTexFilePathOld{\the\CurrentDirectory}{2012}{01},
    \GetTexFilePathExpandableOld{\the\CurrentDirectory}{2012}{02}

\CurrentDirectory={\SpecialDirectory}
\medskip\par Should \emph{not} have xxx: 
    \GetTexFilePathOld{\the\CurrentDirectory}{2013}{03},
    \GetTexFilePathExpandableOld{\the\CurrentDirectory}{2013}{04}

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip
\noindent\textbf{Paths starting with AAA, BBB, or CCC should not have an xxxx in the path}

\medskip\par
\CurrentDirectory={\NotSpecialDirectory}
Should have xxx in path: 
    \GetTexFilePath{\the\CurrentDirectory}{2012}{05},
    \GetTexFilePathExpandable{\the\CurrentDirectory}{2012}{06}

\CurrentDirectory={\SpecialDirectory}
\medskip\par Should \emph{not} have xxx: 
    \GetTexFilePath{\the\CurrentDirectory}{2013}{07},
    \GetTexFilePathExpandable{\the\CurrentDirectory}{2013}{08}

\CurrentDirectory={\SpecialDirectory}
\medskip\par Should \emph{not} have xxx: 
    \GetTexFilePath{\the\CurrentDirectory}{2013}{09},
    \GetTexFilePathExpandable{\the\CurrentDirectory}{2013}{10}

\CurrentDirectory={\SpecialDirectoryB}
\medskip\par Should \emph{not} have xxx: 
    \GetTexFilePath{\the\CurrentDirectory}{2013}{01},
    \GetTexFilePathExpandable{\the\CurrentDirectory}{2013}{11}
\bigskip
\end{document}
```

Comment: No function with `x` in the argument specifiers is fully expandable; you probably are thinking to `\str_if_eq_x:nnTF`

Comment: @egreg: So does that just mean the function is misnamed `\GetTexFilePathExpandable`, or is there really no difference in those two function. I don't recall why, but there was a case where I needed to use `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` instead of `\NewDocumentCommand` to get things to work.  Perhaps that was before I changed to using `\str_if_eq`. Would be happy to eliminate redundant code if those two are identical.

Comment: It depends in what context you need those macros; but they are just the same (apart from minor details).

Comment: @egreg: Re your first comment: Using `\str_if_eq_x:nnTF` in `\GetTexFilePathOld` or `\GetTexFilePathExpandable` breaks things as is the case with this MWE.  Re your second comment: I am using these macros to determine where appropriate files should be, test to see if they exist, add links to them, and perhaps even `\include` them (after similarly generating the appropriate file name and adding an extension based on the context.

Comment: I have two questions: 1) is the first argument to `\GetTexFilePath` always going to be a macro? 2) Do you want to detect the macro names that contain the directories (i.e. `\SpecialDirectory`) or their expansion (i.e. `AAA`)?

Comment: @cgnieder: 1) The first parameter will either be a token defined single value, or a macro with a single value.  2) I _think_ that I want the expansion. The `\ListOfSpecialDirectories` and the `\protected\def`s that it uses does _not_ change at run time, it is a fixed list with fixed value upon start up.  However, the first parameter to `\GetTexFilePath` _can_ change during compilation at different points in the document.

Comment: But if they're `\protected` they _won't_ be expanded in any test using an `x` type argument (i.e. an `\edef`)!

Comment: @cgnieder: Sorry, I really don't get expansion so am not able to properly respond to you. The `\str_if_eq:xxTF` macro works for me, I just need something with identical behavior except that instead of comparing a string it searches for a matching member in a CSV list.  The current solution is not matching in functionality of `\str_if_eq:xxTF`.

Comment: @cgnieder: Also, I could have a separate `\def` for use in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this really answers your needs, which I can't understand precisely.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\GetTeXFilePath}{m m m}
 {
  \grill_str_if_eq_x_in:nVTF { #1 } \ListOfSpecialDirectories {#1/#2/#3} {#1/xxx#2/#3}
 }

\bool_new:N \l__grill_path_bool
\prg_new_protected_conditional:Npnn \grill_str_if_eq_x_in:nn #1 #2 { T,F,TF }
 {
  \bool_set_false:N \l__grill_path_bool
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \str_if_eq_x:nnT { #1 } { ##1 }
     { \clist_map_break:n { \bool_set_true:N \l__grill_path_bool } }
   }
   \bool_if:NTF \l__grill_path_bool
    { \prg_return_true: }
    { \prg_return_false: }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \grill_str_if_eq_x_in:nnTF { nV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\SpecialDirectory{AAA}
\def\SpecialDirectoryB{BBB}
\def\SpecialDirectoryC{CCC}
\newcommand{\ListOfSpecialDirectories}{\SpecialDirectory, \SpecialDirectoryB, \SpecialDirectoryC}

\begin{document}
\GetTeXFilePath{AAA}{2012}{05}

\GetTeXFilePath{\SpecialDirectoryB}{2012}{05}

\GetTeXFilePath{DDD}{2012}{05}
\end{document}
```

This will print

> AAA/2012/05
>   BBB/2012/05
>   DDD/xxx2012/05

but of course this can't be used in an expandable context. However, if you want to use the result, just say

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\GetTeXFilePath}{m m m}
 {
  \grill_str_if_eq_x_in:nVTF { #1 } \ListOfSpecialDirectories
    { \tl_set:Nn \l_grill_result_tl {#1/#2/#3} }
    { \tl_set:Nn \l_grill_result_tl {#1/xxx#2/#3} }
 }
```

and use `\l_grill_result_tl` for passing it to some other macro.

Comment: This seems to work for at least the my use case. I did notice that it failed with `\protected\def\SpecialDirectory{AAA}` and `\GetTeXFilePath{AAA}{2012}{05}`, but I won't be using it like that. I use it as `\GetTeXFilePath{\SpecialDirectory}{2012}{05}` which works fine. Adapting now fo my actual usage...

Comment: Yes, `\protected` inhibits expansion in `\edef` and this is something you don't want in this case.

Comment: I needed to use `\protect` based on [How to expand values stored in a token defined by newtoks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46323/how-to-expand-values-stored-in-a-token-defined-by-newtoks). So, just to clarify, using it as `\protected\def\SpecialDirectory{AAA}` and `\GetTeXFilePath{\SpecialDirectory}{2012}{05}` should _not_ cause any issues, as it does work indeed appear to work in the MWE.

Comment: @PeterGrill This is because I used `\str_if_eq_x:nnT`; it wouldn't with `\str_if_eq:xxT`

Comment: @PeterGrill Sorry, `\tl_set:Nn`

Comment: Any change of getting a version that behaves exactly like `\str_if_eq:xxTF` except that it test being a member of a list. My tests with  `\str_if_eq:xxTF` have worked fine for a while now. Sorry that this is not clear, I really don't know why I am having such a hard time explaining things when it comes to file name and paths.